# Issue with running json-server on AWS server (returning 404)

Tags: amazon-web-services, localhost, json-server

I have been developing an app on my localhost, which I am now hosting on AWS. The app uses json-server to return dummy data and it is working fine on my laptop. However, I can't see to get it working on my AWS server. On the AWS server, json-server is installed and it is starting as expected: -

```
json-server jsonserver.db.json --port 9001

Loading jsonserver.db.json
Done

Resources
http://localhost:9001/urlone

Home
http://localhost:9001
```

But it only returns 404 from a get request (in my console): -

```
http://localhost:9001/urlone/1 0 ()
```

However, if I have json-server running on my localhost (the laptop I a developing from) then the page loads OK. So it seems obvious the GET request is being rooted to my own localhost rather than that of the server.

Is there anyway I can alter this so the server sends the get request to it's own localhost?

Answer (score 3):

Run JSON-Server with the following parameters:

```
--host 'Private IPs'
```

For example:

```
json-server --host 172.31.88.188 --port 80 db.json
```

This works for me in AWS on Ubuntu Server.

Comment: If you use Windows Server, you need turn off Windows Firewall or set rules.